# Creating movable objects in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to design a chess-like game with movable pieces, but I can't figure out how do move the def functions I've created. Can anyone help me?

My code so far is below:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed("fastest")

def bluethyngg1():
    t.fillcolor("blue")
    t.pencolor("blue")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-110,150)
    t.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(20)
        t.rt(90)
    t.end_fill()

def bluethyngg2():
    t.fillcolor("blue")
    t.pencolor("blue")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-110,110)
    t.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(20)
        t.rt(90)
    t.end_fill()

def bluethyngg3():
    t.fillcolor("blue")
    t.pencolor("blue")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-150,110)
    t.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(20)
        t.rt(90)
    t.end_fill()
```

Comment: Turtle isn't usually interactive. You probably want to use something like pygame instead.